# R Vector Format Issue

Tags: r

I have the date in two format:

```
c(`2` = 24.0336327194876, `3` = 24.0799077818911, `4` = 24.0300730993027, 
`6` = 24.0870270222609, `9` = 24.0015961378236, `12` = 24.0193942387481)
```

And:

```
[1] 18.093 32.483 19.133 28.103 22.592 21.137 19.828 20.919 23.657 13.582 24.396
```

I am new to R. I don't understand what the difference between these two data types.

I want plot these to data frame into a same plot, but I run into problems. Is thit possible to make the first type of data into the second type?

Thanks!

Comment: What problems are you running into? The first vector is named, but that shouldn't affect plotting. They are different lengths, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a call to `unname()`. For example:

```
a <- c(`2` = 24.0336327194876, `3` = 24.0799077818911, `4` = 24.0300730993027, 
`6` = 24.0870270222609, `9` = 24.0015961378236, `12` = 24.0193942387481)

unname(a)
[1] 24.03363 24.07991 24.03007 24.08703 24.00160 24.01939
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask one more question? What does the unname(a) return? Is it still a vector or a list?

Comment: It's a vector. You can check with `is.vector(unname(a))`.